# scala spray class file name too long

Tags: scala, sbt, shapeless, scala-2.11

I am trying to build a jar of my spray project with sbt assembly. However, I find that some of the class files generated have very long names/paths. Following is one such long path -

```
./target/streams/$global/assemblyOption/$global/streams/assembly/3c0b4d67b1c9790a43fbe9de56f99ec0d020c046_3b7c2ebd20b599b3521aab75df549c774b4bbe23/shapeless/TupleTypeableInstances$$anon$20$$anonfun$cast$16$$anonfun$apply$106$$anonfun$apply$107$$anonfun$apply$108$$anonfun$apply$109$$anonfun$apply$110$$anonfun$apply$111$$anonfun$apply$112$$anonfun$apply$113$$anonfun$apply$114$$anonfun$apply$115.class
```

This builds on my local mac, but I am not able to install my project jar on a linux machine.

I tried the '-Xmax-classfile-name' option, but that doesn't seem to be helping.

Is there any way to shorten the path/name of the files generated?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're trying to compile this on an ecryptfs, I was running into the same problem. Only my home directory is encrypted, thus I moved the sources for the problematic Scala projects out of that. Have a look at https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly/issues/69 and the linked discussion.